# Returned JSON from PHP isn't properly processed by jQuery.each() to display as new markers on the Google Map

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I return **JSON** data from a **PHP** script, generated with `SQL`, to my client's `jQuery.each()`, based on what user has selected in the filtering form and clicked **Submit**, to update and display all the returned `JSON` data as markers on my Google Map.

***Problem is*** instead of displaying the returned `JSON` data as new markers it just *bounds* on the already displayed markers ( the default ones when page is initially loaded ).

What am I doing wrong here?

I use [this jQuery plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-map/) to work with my Google Map.

My returned JSON looks like this:

```
[{"Name":"John Smith","Address":"123 Fake St.", "Telephone":"50011111" ,"Lat":"coord values","Lng":"coord values"},{...repeat...},{}]
```

**Jquery for submit button:**

```
$('#myform').on('submit', function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var myData = $('#myform').serializeArray();
                    $.getJSON('phpscript.php', myData, function(json){
                        var theMarkers = json;
                        // alert(JSON.stringify(json));
                        $.each(theMarkers, function(i, val) {                           
                            $('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', { 'position': new google.maps.LatLng(val.Lat, val.Lng), 'bounds':true, 'icon':'mymarker.png' } ).click(function(){                               
                                $('#map_canvas').gmap('openInfoWindow', { 'content': '<h1>'+val.Name+'</h1>'+'<h2 style="color: grey">'+val.Address+'</h2><p style="color: green">'+val.Telephone+'</p>' }, this);
                            });                     
                        });

                    }); 
                });
```

Comment: instead of `alert()`, use `console.log(json)`, check firebug in FF, and report back.

Comment: @Xeoncross: I did like you said. In FF's Web Console I see my filtered JSON data returned, just like the one I've provided as an example in my original post.

Comment: then the next step is to `console.log(val)` inside the $.each loop to see what that value is. We need to make sure that the data you are expecting is actually what is making it through your code. You also never mentioned the name of the **jQuery Google Maps Plugin** you seem to be using which might be the real problem.

Comment: @Xeoncross: Now the Web Console shows the same JSON data, but it is segmented into individual elements like so: `({"Name":"John Smith","Address":"123 Fake St.", "Telephone":"50011111" ,"Lat":"coord values","Lng":"coord values"})`

Comment: @Xeoncross: My bad. I forgot to mention that I use this jQuery plugin to work with Google Maps: http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-map/

Comment: You need to keep testing things. Does `$('#map_canvas')` exist? Are there any errors with `console.log(val.Name)`? Looks like you are matching [the sample code](http://jquery-ui-map.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/jquery-google-maps-json.html).

Comment: @Xeoncross: I think it works now. It worked all along. I just had to clear the old markers first to see new ones, instead the new ones were simply being place on the same spot as the old ones. This made it look like nothing worked. Although for some reason the map doesn't _bound_ to the markers, but I'll try to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything works fine. You have to call this just before populating the map with new markers.

```
$('#map_canvas').gmap('clear', 'markers');
```

Answer (score 1):

You do realise that in your `$.each` function, `i` is the index, and `val` is the object in the current iteration.

Are you sure it should'nt be `val.Name`, `val.Address` etc. as that would access those values in your json object, on the other hand `i.name` will probably just be the current index, like `4.name` etc. ??

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I've edited the source code in the original post to match my current one. I do indeed use the `val` instead of `i`, yet it still doesn't show the filtered/new markers on the map. If I will use the `i` instead - my map gets shaded in grat color, withut the ability to zoom in/out, and no markers at all.

Answer (score 1):

Two thoughts:

(1) Do Lat and Lng really say `coord values` and not real numbers? (I'm reading the comments literally)

(2) Does `mymarker.png` exist (right path) and load properly in the browser? Since I don't have this file, when I tested, nothing appeared until I removed it from the source.

I used this to test and it worked fine, with the latest jquery-ui-map downloaded. I just assumed the jQuery ajax part works fine because you are outputting the expected results in the console.

```
<html>
 <head>
 <style type="text/css">
  html, body, #map_canvas { margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100% }
 </style>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqueryuimap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var map;
  var mapOptions = { center: new google.maps.LatLng(0.0, 0.0), zoom: 2,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP };

  function initialize() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
    theMarkers = [
      {"Name":"John Smith","Address":"123 Fake St.", 
         "Telephone":"50011111" ,"Lat":"0.0","Lng":"0.0"},

      {"Name":"John Smith","Address":"123 Fake St.", 
         "Telephone":"50011111" ,"Lat":"10.0","Lng":"0.0"},

      {"Name":"John Smith","Address":"123 Fake St.", 
         "Telephone":"50011111" ,"Lat":"20.0","Lng":"0.0"}
    ]

    $.each(theMarkers, function(i, val) {
      $('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', 
        { 'position': new google.maps.LatLng(val.Lat, val.Lng), 
          'bounds':true } ).click(function(){                               
      $('#map_canvas').gmap('openInfoWindow', 
        { 'content': '<h1>'+val.Name+'</h1>'+
          '<h2 style="color: grey">'+val.Address+
          '</h2><p style="color: green">'+val.Telephone+'</p>' }, this);
       });   
    });
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

Comment: Turns out it worked all along - that's why it worked for you too. Thing is, I filter my markers based on what user specified in my form's controls by sending the form data to a PHP script. PHP script would then grab the form data and apply it to my SQL statement and return the results as JSON back to my jQuery. I just had to clear the old markers and then plot the new ones, but I didn't do it - instead I plotted the new ones right over the old ones. I've posted my own answer if you want to see it.